# can not load audio folder on colab while using huggin face datasets api

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, huggingface-datasets

i am trying to load a datasets from my google drive, by using load_dataset and audio folder, but im getting an error saying that the folder doesnt contain any data files. it does contain file in .wav format. the link is open to everyone

```
EmptyDatasetError: The directory at /content/https:/drive.google.com/file/d/1KfE5Zy05U493nQGvPM9hR9Aw3SkBXcPG/view?usp=share_link doesn't contain any data files
```

```
%%capture
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/datasets.git
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
!pip install torchaudio
!pip install librosa
!pip install jiwer

import os
import pandas as pd

from datasets import load_dataset
datasets_url_male = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WoiL-EnihErYK9NEpohq_sJfwPJkXDb1'
datasets_url_female = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iq2gI5sHQq3pK3JHL3UgBt_EyvTc2IFy'
datasets_url_folder = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KfE5Zy05U493nQGvPM9hR9Aw3SkBXcPG/view?usp=share_link'
#dataset = load_dataset("audiofolder", data_dir="/path/to/folder")
dataset = load_dataset("audiofolder",data_dir=datasets_url_folder)
```